# *ngIf поздно подгружает svg/gif

Tags: css, angular

*ngIf вставляет в разметку блок с текстом и icon.svg. Текс и блок подгружается моментально, а вот иконка тупит секунды 2-4.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробывал делать на нативном js подменяя стили block и flex, работает норм, причина - потому что если использовать display: block то елемент сразу подружен на странице а *ngIf работает реактивно и подгружает в первый раз. Как все таки использовать *ngIf без задержки.

Comment: Возможно, что ngIf срабатывает позже, а изначально он находится в значении false. Так как он false, то самой загрузки svg файла не происходит. Можно заменить его на hidden, тогда иконка должна загрузиться сразу в шаблон, но не будет отображенна